# Using boost::hana and CMake without full boost install (external project?)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-hana

I recently downloaded the newest boost library to get access to boost::hana and read on their documentation [page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html)  that they suggest using the "FindHana.cmake module to setup Hana as an external project for use."

I couldn't figure this out so I just set the compile flags to include my hana.hpp to the header path, but I'd love to know how to accomplish this the way suggested in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In upcoming versions of Boost, Hana provides a file called `HanaConfig.cmake`, which is installed in `<install-prefix>/lib/cmake/hana/HanaConfig.cmake` automatically when you type `make install`. Then, provided your `<install-prefix>` is part of the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` (which will be the case if you install it to a default, system-wide location), you just need to:

```
find_package(Hana)
target_link_libraries(some-target hana)
```

This will add the right include directories to `some-target`. This is the right way to depend on other CMake projects, and I changed Hana's way of doing it recently (on `develop` only right now) in light of this.

Comment: Is it possible to use CMake and find_package(Hana) without running make install? It's the idea of adding to the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH that I'm most interested in.

Comment: No, because `make install` is what will put the `HanaConfig.cmake` file in place, and that is what `find_package` looks for. That being said, it does not mean that you need to install Hana in a system-wide location. You can install Hana locally and pass the right `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` without problem. See [dyno](https://github.com/ldionne/dyno) for example.

Comment: between this comment and this link I got it worked out. https://blogs.kde.org/2008/12/12/how-get-cmake-find-what-you-want-it

Answer (score 0):

In cmake, the `find_package( SomePackage )` function will run `Find<SomePackage>.cmake`.  In lots of cases `Find<SomePackage>.cmake` is included in the cmake installation.  If not, then you need add that file to your project structure and append the path of that file to CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.

I did a quick search to find [this](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/cmake/FindHana.cmake).  In that case, this is how you'd use it:

```
find_package( Hana )

if ( ${Hana_FOUND} )
  include_directories( ${Hana_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
endif()
```

If `${Hana_FOUND}` isn't set by the script, you can set `Hana_ROOT` or `Hana_INSTALL_PREFIX` to give the script better hints about where to find it.

---

You also mention boost.  Boost is slightly different and wouldn't use `FindHana`.  Boost is its own monster, but there is some documentation for finding boost [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/FindBoost.html).  In the case of boost::hana, you'd use `FindBoost` like so:

```
find_package(Boost)
if ( ${Boost_FOUND} )
  include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
endif()
```

if you have problems, you can try setting `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` and `BOOST_ROOT` to help cmake find your installation.

Comment: I have worked out the boost find_package business thank goodness. I think my troubles stem from the fact that I didn't install Hana I only wanted to include the header file.

Comment: If you have already installed boost, it includes a [hana library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html).  You should just need to `#include <boost/hana.hpp>` and `namespace hana = boost::hana` without any need to install anything further.

Comment: My situation is a little convoluted, and I'll probably edit my post to reflect this, but the boost I have "installed" isn't the one that includes the hana header. I was interested in trying out hana so I downloaded the most recent library to my home, without running make install in this new boost directory is it possible to use find_package(hana)? Sorry if I'm going about asking this question the wrong way, I'm just starting with stack...

Comment: [Try this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html).  You can indeed try out hana without using the boost-supplied version.  Three other ways are described at that link.  You can get the sources from [github](https://github.com/boostorg/hana)